# opening link in same window using jquery

Tags: jquery

.bind('click',function(){
        window.open($(this).find('.pc_more').html());
    });
});

is there something in this part of the code that tells it to open the link in a new page? can i put some code to open the link in the same window?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for:

```
.bind('click', function(){
    window.location = $(this).find('.pc_more').html();
});
```

...assuming that the element matched by `.pc_more` really has a link as its *HTML*.

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/uwogi4/2)

Comment: $pc_wrapper.find('.pc_item').hover(
 function(){
  $(this).addClass('selected');
 },
 function(){
  $(this).removeClass('selected');
 }
).bind('click',function(){
  window.location($(this).find('.pc_more').html());
 });
}); 

this is actually all the code that i should have pasted in the first place. Whats happening is on the website i am working on it has a panel that slide across the scree, and it has images. When you put your mouse over the image the 'pc_wrapper' appears and when you click, it opens the link that i added to the image in a new page and would like it to open in the same page

Comment: wait nvm i got it! thanks so much! i just needed to change .open to .location. I appreciate the help =]

Answer (score 3):

Try using window.location instead of window.open().

```
window.location = $(this).find('.pc_more').html();
```