# How to open a new page in the same window based on jquery-ajax response

Tags: php, jquery

This might be easy but I'm having trouble doing this right. How can I open a new page in the same window using jquery-ajax response?

As you can see I'm trying to display a custom text if the php response is equal to the word "invalid". If not open a new html page in the same window.

```
   $("#lBtn").click(function(){
      $.post("php/session.php",
        { username:$("#username").val(), 
          password:$("#password").val()
        },
        function(response) {
          alert(response)
          if(response == "invalid"){
             $("#loginResponse").text("Error!!");
          } else {
             window.location = $(this).find('new/pahe.html').html();
            }
        });
    });
```

Alert(response) shows the word "invalid" but the if statement does not work. Means neither it display `Error!!` in `$("#loginResponse")` nor it opens the new page. That's what I want to fix.

Comment: whats this supposed to do: `$(this).find('new/pahe.html').html();`

Comment: @fox: avoid opening a page in a new tab or similar

Comment: @Steve: open a fresh URL

Comment: @fox: No exit from the current page and go to a fresh URL.

Comment: replace with `window.location = "http://www.mozilla.org";` and it will work. My point was what this `$(this).find('new/pahe.html').html();` looks wrong

Comment: specifically that `.find()` accepts a selector: http://api.jquery.com/find/ `new/pahe.html` does not look like a selector to me

Comment: @Steve: You might be right. I was googling and came across this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588701/opening-link-in-same-window-using-jquery). That's how I end up using it.

Comment: `window.location = "new/pahe.html";` perhaps? Or is that not the correct url? Im a bit confused as to what you are asking

Comment: @Steve: alert(response) shows the word "invalid" but the if statement does not work. Means it does not display `Error!!`in `$("#loginResponse")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably getting additional white-space returned in the output from the post (maybe a carriage return or space?).

Trim the response:

```
function(response) {
    response = $.trim(response);
    if(response == "invalid"){
```

or just do this to check for a sub-string match:

```
function(response) {
    if(response.indexOf("invalid")>=0){
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: You did not word your question right. What you are aiming to do is to redirect to another page.

If `#lBtn`'s html is the url itself, the solution to that is to use:

```
window.location.href = $(this).html();
```

---

This is for opening the link in a new tab

First create a new link, hidden somewhere:

**Javascript code**

```
$('body').append('<a id="new_wnd_temp" href="another_page.html" target="_blank" style="display:none"></a>');
```

Then trigger a click event on it:

**Javascript code**

```
$('#new_wnd_temp').trigger('click').remove();
```

In your example, it would look like this:

**Javascript code**

```
$("#lBtn").click(function() {
    $.post("php/session.php", {
        username:$("#username").val(), 
        password:$("#password").val()
    },
    function(response) {
        alert(response);

        if(response == "invalid") {
            $("#loginResponse").text("Error!!");
        } else {
            $('body').append('<a id="new_wnd_temp" href="another_page.html" target="_blank" style="display:none"></a>');
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#new_wnd_temp').trigger('click').remove();
            }, 0);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. But my problem is that `alert(response)` shows the word "invalid" but the if statement does not work. Means neither it display `Error!!` in `$("#loginResponse")` nor it opens the new page. That's what I want to fix.

Comment: That is likely because you have a whitespace character before or after the php script. Instead of `response == "invalid"`, try using `response.replace(" ", "") == 'invalid"`. If that still doesn't work, try with removing the `\n` character as well.